# Keyboard shortcuts for Adobe Reader on ChromeBook/ChromeOs

Tags: android, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader, chromebook

I am unable to find even the most basic capabilities - starting with `PageUp` / `PageDown`.  The normal keys for those `Alt-UpArrow` and `Alt-DownArrow` only scroll one line - which is exactly what just the `UpArrow` / `DownArrow` *without* the `Alt`.

I was also unable to find out how to jump to a page number. There will be more - except given the lack of paging I'm putting usage of this app on hold.

BTW is this the same App as used across all *Android* devices? I am thinking it is - given it is installed via `Google Play`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution: use Chrome

<kbd>Page Up</kbd> and <kbd>Page Down</kbd> work without issues in Chrome's built in PDF interpreter and you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to [jump to a specific page number](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/OIxppVLDLFg).

You can make Chrome go full screen through the menu's zoom options, the F11 function key or use the Chromebooks full screen [key](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/1047364?hl=en):

> [image: full screen key] Hide the tabs and launcher in full-screen Immersive mode (F4)

## Keyboard shortcuts in Acrobat Reader app

It looks like the Adobe Acrobat Reader app (version 18.2) doesn't play well in the Android apps for Chromebooks environment at the moment. If you go to settings you can find an option called **enable shortcuts** *to improve navigation with paired keyboards* (sorry I'm using my device in German, I have to guess here). When I enable this setting though it still won't recognize [Chromebook shortcuts](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/183101?hl=en) or the keys from my external keyboard.

It also doesn't detect external storage with Chrome OS 67 as far as I can tell, I thought this problem was solved in Chrome OS already.

## Acrobat Reader isn't always the best option to view PDF

> BTW is this the same App as used across all Android devices?

Yes this is the same app used across all Android devices. From my point of view using Android since 1.5 and Desktop Linux distros as a daily driver for about 10 years now almost nobody cares about Adobe Reader to read PDF documents when the document in question has already been opened by a different app. PDF support in Chrome was [introduced](https://blog.chromium.org/2010/06/bringing-improved-pdf-support-to-google.html) to make browsing faster and safer. There even was an FSF/FSFE [campaign](https://www.fsf.org/bulletin/2010/fall/pdf-readers) against »Get Adobe Reader« brand awareness advertisements where and whenever PDF is used, which probably was a bit controversial.

Comment: Thx for that detailed investigation.  If you find better pdf readers later on pls append to your answer.

Comment: A concern with the built in is **how to make it go full screen**. I can *not* afford to lose real estate on an already-small-ish chromebook screen.  The Adobe reader *on other platforms* - e.g. `ios` has a few features that make it meaningfully better than the half dozen other readers  I have tried.

Comment: I  selected the "enable shortcuts": but I still can not get anything to do pageup/pagedown or go to page.

Comment: I'm not sure if Adobe can do anything about the keyboard shortcuts not working on Chrome OS and if there has been a bug reported to Adobe to make them aware of this or if this is entirely up to Chrome OS developers making this functionality work. I updated my answer regarding full screen functionality in Chrome. It works well here, just wait a second and you only have the document on screen without any screen space wasted.

Answer (score 0):

Adding details to the accepted answer from @LiveWireBT:

Here are the shortcuts for Adobe Acrobat Reader on Chromebook. They do *NOT* have PageUp/PageDown *or* Go to Page. **Goodbye Acrobat** !

[image]

I will be looking for alternatives *that have solid paired keyboard support* .